# How can I preserve both matching and non-matching parts using immutable collection in O(n) time

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have to operate on `tmp` list based on some condition.
`false` does a bulk db `insert` and `true` does an `update`

```
val tmp = List(1,2,3, 15)
val bool = List(true, true, true, false)
```

I am using the below approach to create 2 lists , one matching and one non-matching.

```
val result = tmp.zip(bool).partition {
case tuple if tuple._2 => true
case tuple if !tuple._2 => false
}
```

I get 2 lists , so I can run `insertAll(result._2)` and `updateAll(result._1)`

Since `partition` uses `scala.collection.mutable.Builder`, I was trying to find an approach that solves the problem using immutable collections.

Comment: Any sensible partition algorithm is going to be `O(n)` so this is not relevant. Are you looking for a pure version of `partition` that does not use mutable data structures? If so, try writing your own a recursive solution and ask again if you have problems.

Comment: Note that you can simplify your code: `tmp.zip(bool).partition(_._2)` and by using a view you can avoid iterating multiple times over intermediate collections.

Regarding the use of the mutable builder, note that many methods in the Scala Collection API make use of them, e.g. `zip` itself: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/StrictOptimizedIterableOps.scala#L184-L191

Comment: @Tim. Thanks, I will try to use recursion. Yes, I wanted to use a pure version with no mutable collection.

Comment: @ForeverLearner Then you would need to avoid anything in the stdlib. As much as I also love pure functional programming, and as much as I am always immutable with my own implementations, I do not avoid everything in the stdlib because they are useful and efficient.

Comment: I assume OP was interested in this mostly from an educational perspective.

Comment: I regularly use the stdlib in my daily work. But to have a better understanding of scala , I was trying to find possible parts of my code that is using mutable collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with two solutions. I don't find either fully satisfactory but hopefully they can help you achieve your goal.

The first one is tail recursive but reverses the original input. It may be enough for your use case if you don't care about the order, but if you do you have to reverse the resulting lists before returning them, which involves a second pass through the list (`O(n)`):

```
def zipAndPartition[A, B](as: List[A], bs: List[B])(p: ((A, B)) => Boolean): (List[(A, B)], List[(A, B)]) = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(left: List[A], right: List[B], acc: (List[(A, B)], List[(A, B)])): (List[(A, B)], List[(A, B)]) =
    (left, right) match {
      case (Nil, _) | (_, Nil) => acc
      case (lhead :: ltail, rhead :: rtail) if p((lhead, rhead)) => loop(ltail, rtail, ((lhead, rhead) :: acc._1, acc._2))
      case (lhead :: ltail, rhead :: rtail) => loop(ltail, rtail, (acc._1, (lhead, rhead) :: acc._2))
    }

  val (left, right) = loop(as, bs, (Nil, Nil))
  (left.reverse, right.reverse)
}
```

The second doesn't require reversing the outputs before returning them but relies on mutually recursive functions and thus cannot be annotated with `@annotation.tailrec`:

```
def zap[A, B](as: List[A], bs: List[B])(p: ((A, B)) => Boolean): (List[(A, B)], List[(A, B)]) = {
  def loop(left: List[A], right: List[B], acc: (List[(A, B)], List[(A, B)])): (List[(A, B)], List[(A, B)]) =
    (left, right) match {
      case (Nil, _) | (_, Nil) => acc
      case (lhead :: ltail, rhead :: rtail) if p((lhead, rhead)) =>
        val tail = zap(ltail, rtail)(p)
        ((lhead, rhead) :: tail._1, tail._2)
      case (lhead :: ltail, rhead :: rtail) =>
        val tail = zap(ltail, rtail)(p)
        (tail._1, (lhead, rhead) :: tail._2)
    }

  loop(as, bs, (Nil, Nil))
}
```

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/8Xr6oI7tSLauISXZKHqL0Q/5).

#### Edit

A third solution, which retains the shortcomings of the first but is probably more readable, splits the problem in two and uses function composition:

```
val tmp = List(1, 2, 3, 15)
val bool = List(true, true, true, false)

def zip[A, B](as: List[A], bs: List[B]): List[(A, B)] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(left: List[A], right: List[B], acc: List[(A, B)]): List[(A, B)] =
    (left, right) match {
      case (Nil, _) | (_, Nil) => acc
      case (lhead :: ltail, rhead :: rtail) => loop(ltail, rtail, (lhead, rhead) :: acc)
    }
  loop(as, bs, Nil)
}

def partition[A](as: List[A])(p: A => Boolean): (List[A], List[A]) = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(list: List[A], acc: (List[A], List[A])): (List[A], List[A]) =
    list match {
      case Nil => acc
      case head :: tail if p(head) => loop(tail, (head :: acc._1, acc._2))
      case head :: tail => loop(tail, (acc._1, head:: acc._2))
    }
  loop(as, (Nil, Nil))
}

def zap[A, B] = (zip[A, B] _).tupled.andThen(partition[(A, B)] _)

zap(tmp, bool)(_._2)
```

This solution is [available on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/8Xr6oI7tSLauISXZKHqL0Q/18) as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is a recursive partition function using immutable data

```
def part[T](list: List[T])(f: T => Boolean): (List[T], List[T]) = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(rem: List[T], res1: List[T], res2: List[T]): (List[T], List[T]) =
    rem match {
      case Nil =>
        (res1.reverse, res2.reverse)
      case hd :: tail =>
        if (f(hd)) {
          loop(tail, hd +: res1, res2)
        } else {
          loop(tail, res1, hd +: res2)
        }
    }

  loop(list, Nil, Nil)
}
```

This solution is built in reverse to keep the algorithm `O(n)`